# C++ Using promise/future with multiple threads & receiving a thread result ASAP

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program (school exercise) that runs 4 threads and each thread generates random numbers from 0-4095, if a number is above 4000 I should print it. This has to be done using promise / future. Program should run as long as keyboard is pressed

What I have is a semi working solution with a problem. I manage to get 4 threads to perform tasks and set value, however in calling thread I currently receive result with get_future().get() on each promise variable.

```
cout << "1: " << num1.get_future().get() << endl;
cout << "2: " << num2.get_future().get() << endl;
cout << "3: " << num3.get_future().get() << endl;
cout << "4: " << num4.get_future().get() << endl;
```

While it works, each of these calls blocks calling thread until value is received, meaning threads 2,3,4 might all have values set already but they are not accessed before thread 1 gets value set.

Hence my question, how can I implement promise / future so that I could receive / print out value as soon as one is set and would not need to wait on others.

complete code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Sensor
{
public:

    void generateNumber(promise<int>& num)
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 4095);

        int x = distr(gen);

        while (x < 4001)
        {
            x = distr(gen);
        }

        num.set_value(x);
    }

};

class SensorReader
{
public:

    string startGenerating()
    {
        while(!_kbhit())
        {
            promise<int> num1, num2, num3, num4;

            Sensor sensor;

            thread t1(&Sensor::generateNumber, &sensor, ref(num1));
            thread t2(&Sensor::generateNumber, &sensor, ref(num2));
            thread t3(&Sensor::generateNumber, &sensor, ref(num3));
            thread t4(&Sensor::generateNumber, &sensor, ref(num4));

            cout << "1: " << num1.get_future().get() << endl;
            cout << "2: " << num2.get_future().get() << endl;
            cout << "3: " << num3.get_future().get() << endl;
            cout << "4: " << num4.get_future().get() << endl;
            
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t4.join();
        }

        return "Finished!";
    }   
};

int main()
{
    SensorReader numbers;
    cout << numbers.startGenerating() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use mutexes and condition variables? Did you try using a mutex, condition variables, and simple flags which each execution thread sets and then signals the condition variable every time it returns a promise? So your main thread can easily use it to determine which thread has finished executing and has its promised returned value?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes we did cover mutexes and condition variables but the task is to solve with using promise / future.

Comment: I never said you should not use a promise and a future. But you also need to use a mutex and a condition variable, and a few other things, together with promises and futures, as I already explained to you.

Comment: Do you need `std::ref` here?

Comment: If you're using C++14 or newer, you can when_any().

Comment: the most natural solution is to have a common blocking queue, 4 generating threads write to it, and the main thread reads. Futures do not fit here.